# pass variables to a function in bash(weird output?)

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

```
function f(){
local y=$1;
local z=$2;
echo $x $y $z;
}
function main(){
x=1;
y=2;
z=3;
f $y $z;
}

main $*
```

My output is 1 2 3

Why does this happen? I only passed two variables y and z.

$1 would be y from main which is 2 so back in function f local y=$1 would be y=2. The same thing for local z=$2, it would be z=3.

So I would assume either an error because I'm trying to echo $x which isn't a valid variable or I should get 2 3.

Why does it echo out 1 2 3?

Answer (score 2):

`$x` is a global variable. The fact that it is assigned within a function doesn't change that.

So of course it is visible in `f()` or any other function.

Comment: I'm new to bash, can you tell me what makes it a global variable?
The fact that i didn't declare it as a local in main or does the dollar sign somehow make it a global variable? I'm confused. This is different from Java which i'm used to.

Comment: I added a new function:
function g(){
echo $x;
}

It doesn't print out anything, so from what you are saying it should have printed x which is 1, however only the echo from function f that was called from main get's outputed.

Comment: That's just how bash works: unless declared local, a variable is global. The dollar sign is just how you access the value of the variable; it has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: It sounds like you called `g` before you called `main`, at which point `x` doesn't yet have a value.

Comment: @user1880760, global variables used to be available in all languages, but they have fallen out of fashion in the modern era.  In Java terms, imagine a single class (maybe called *"global"*) with a bunch of static variables, and imagine that anything not specifically marked local is actually one of these statics. Yes, every single function and module in the entire program shares the namespace. (That's why they are out of fashion now.)  For small programs like shell scripts, though, they work perfectly well.